# Converting integer Seconds values into datetime. Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to automate the conversion of an array of seconds into datetime. I'm very familiar with converting the seconds from 1970 into datetime, but the values that I have here are for the seconds elapsed in a given day. For example, 14084 is the number if seconds that has passed on 2011,11,11, and I was able to generate the datetime below.

```
str(dt.timedelta(seconds = 14084))
Out[245]: '3:54:44'

dt.datetime.combine(date(2011,11,11),time(3,54,44))
Out[250]: datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 11, 3, 54, 44)
```

Is there a faster way of conversion for an array.

Comment: take a look at [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

Comment: Why don't you just do `datetime(2011,11,11) + timedelta(seconds=14084)`?

Comment: @Selcuk I'll try that out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` has support for arrays of datetimes with a timedelta type for manipulating them:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

e.g. you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
date_array = np.arange('2005-02', '2005-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')
date_array += np.timedelta64(4, 's')  # Add 4 seconds
```

If you have an array of seconds, you could convert it into an array of timedeltas and add that to a fixed datetime

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
seconds = [14084, 14085, 15003]
```

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.to_timedelta(seconds, unit='s') + pd.to_datetime('2011-11-11')
series = series.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)

print(series)
0   2011-11-11 03:54:44
1   2011-11-11 03:54:45
2   2011-11-11 04:10:03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or a list comprehension

```
list_comp = [datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 11) +
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=s) for s in seconds]

print(list_comp)
[datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 11, 3, 54, 44), datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 11, 3, 54, 45), datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 11, 4, 10, 3)]
```